# Casting UnsafeMutablePointers to UnsafeMutableRawPointers

Tags: ios, swift, casting, unsafe-pointers, migrating

I have a couple of issues updating to swift 3.0. I have the following code:

```
  // Retrieve the Device GUID
        let device = UIDevice.current
        let uuid = device.identifierForVendor
        let mutableData = NSMutableData(length: 16)
        (uuid! as NSUUID).getBytes(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutableData!.mutableBytes))

        // Verify the hash
        var hash = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: 20)
        var ctx = SHA_CTX()
        SHA1_Init(&ctx)
        SHA1_Update(&ctx, mutableData!.bytes, mutableData!.length)
        SHA1_Update(&ctx, (opaqueData1! as NSData).bytes, opaqueData1!.count)
        SHA1_Update(&ctx, (bundleIdData1! as NSData).bytes, bundleIdData1!.count)
        SHA1_Final(&hash, &ctx)
        let computedHashData1 = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer(&hash), count: 20)
```

My first issue is with the line of code:

```
(uuid! as NSUUID).getBytes(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutableData!.mutableBytes))
```

mutableData!.mutableBytes now returns an UnsafeMutableRawPointer and the compiler complains that "cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_> with an argument of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer)'" Now I have been trying to cast them to the same types but have had no success.

My second issue is with the line:

```
let computedHashData1 = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer(&hash), count: 20)
```

This line causes a compiler error "Ambiguous use of 'init'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue, you can write something like this:

```
    (uuid! as NSUUID).getBytes(mutableData!.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))
```

But if you can accept `Data` having the same raw UUID bytes, you can write it as:

```
    var uuidBytes = uuid!.uuid
    let data = Data(bytes: &uuidBytes, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: uuidBytes))
```

---

Your second issue, in `Data.init(bytes:count:)`, the type of the first parameter is `UnsafeRawPointer`, to which you can pass arbitrary type of `Unsafe(Mutable)Pointer`s.

[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216)

Check the Constant Pointers part of [Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID23).

> When a function is declared as taking an `UnsafeRawPointer` argument,
>   it can accept the same operands as `UnsafePointer<Type>` for any type
>   `Type`.

You have no need to cast pointer types.

```
    let computedHashData1 = Data(bytes: &hash, count: 20)
```